# how can I summarize occurence from another table in a pbi table

Tags: powerbi

I have a full list of events in tableA in a pbi report, created tableB with a unique distinct list of events from tableA, how can I create a new column in tableB to return count the number of occurrences from tableA for each of the distinct events in tableB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Column=CALCULATE ( COUNTX ( FILTER ( 'tblA', 'tblA'[Events] = MAX ( tblB[Events] ) ), 'tblA'[Events] ) )
```

Comment: thanks, this works...... but then I need to extract a list of events from tableB that has less than 5 occurrences, what would the DAX formula look like?

Comment: don't worry, think I got that... filter(tableB, tableB[occurence]<5)